# Can i access Computers file on my Android device through browser

Tags: wireless-networking, network-shares

My Computer with windows 8 and my smartphone with lollipop both are connected to the same router and i want to access files from my PC on Android browser is it possible if yes then please tell me how?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. What have you tried? What research have you done so far?

Comment: 1) Share files on PC.  2) Use a file explorer on Android to access them. Which parts have you tried already, and where exactly are you getting  stuck?

Comment: I can access file from one PC to another on the same n/w but i don't know how to do same between Android and windows within same network

Comment: *Which parts have you tried already, and where exactly are you getting stuck?*

Answer (score 0):

Couple of options that I see for this:

1. Install a web server on your file sharing computer (or computer with access to file share). With the right options and permissions, you can downlaod files in specified folders with http/https
2. Forget the browser and use a  file sharing app like ES File Explorer that you can connect to your computer on the same LAN and access all of your documents